# Pig script on aws emr with tez occasionally fails with OutOfMemoryException

Tags: apache-pig, emr, tez

I have a pig script running on an emr cluster (emr-5.4.0) using a custom UDF. The UDF is used to lookup some dimensional data for which it imports a (somewhat) large amout of text data.

In the pig script, the UDF is used as follows:

```
DEFINE LookupInteger com.ourcompany.LookupInteger(<some parameters>);
```

The UDF stores some data in `Map<Integer, Integer>`

On some input data the aggregation fails with an exception as follows

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2377)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2422)
    [...]
    at com.ourcompany.LocalFileUtil.toMap(LocalFileUtil.java:71)
    at com.ourcompany.LookupInteger.exec(LookupInteger.java:46)
    at com.ourcompany.LookupInteger.exec(LookupInteger.java:19)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:330)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextInteger(POUserFunc.java:379)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:347)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POBinCond.genericGetNext(POBinCond.java:76)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POBinCond.getNextInteger(POBinCond.java:118)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:347)
```

This does not occur when the pig aggregation is run with `mapreduce`, so a workaround for us is to replace `pig -t tez` with `pig -t mapreduce`.

As i'm new to amazon emr, and pig with tez, i'd appreciate some hints on how to analyse or debug the issue.

**EDIT:**
It looks like a strange runtime behaviour while running the pig script on tez stack.

Please note that the pig script is using

- replicated joins (the smaller relations to be joined need to fit into memory) and
- the already mentioned UDF, which is initialising a `Map<Integer, Interger>` producing the aforementioned OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found another workaround using tez backend. Using increased values for `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` and `mapreduce.map.java.opts` (0.8 times of `mapreduce.map.memory.mb`). Those values are bound to the ec2 instance types and are usually fixed values (see [aws emr task config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html)).

By (temporarily) doubling the values, we were able to make the pig script succeed.

The following values were set for a m3.xlarge core instance, which has default values:

- mapreduce.map.java.opts := -Xmx1152m
- mapreduce.map.memory.mb := 1440

Pig startup command

```
pig -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx2304m \
    -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=2880 -stop_on_failure -x tez ... script.pig
```

**EDIT**

One colleague came up with the following idea:

Another workaround for the `OutOfMemory: GC overhead limit exceeded` could be to add explicit `STORE` and `LOAD` statements for the problematic relations, that would make tez flush the data to storage. This could also help in debugging the issue, as the (temporary, intermediate) data can be observed with other pig scripts.